# Kotlin smart cast with Stream

Tags: kotlin

I have interface `A` and class `B: A`

```
val a: Stream<A>

val b: Stream<B> = a.filter { it is B }
                    .map { it as B }
```

Is there a way to write this using Kotlin smart casts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to write this using Kotlin smart casts?

No, this is not possible with basic static analysis as there no indicator that `a`, after being filtered, only contains `B`s, as it is still a `Stream<A>`, so you must check this yourself. Kotlin's smart casting is applied only to the value of a variable and not to a type parameter.

AFAIK there isn't anything that does this in the Java or Kotlin libraries for `Stream`s, but you could [convert the stream to a `Sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.streams/java.util.stream.-stream/as-sequence.html) and use [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html):

```
a.asSequence().filterIsInstance<B>().asStream()
```

Of course, you could also implement this functionality directly on streams with an extension method:

```
inline fun <reified B> Stream<*>.filterIsInstance() = a.filter { it is B }.map { it as B }

...

val a: Stream<A>
val b: Stream<B> = a.filterIsInstance<B>()
```

---

Just a comment: do you need to use `Stream`s? I would consider using Kotlin's `Sequence`s from the start instead.

Comment: I have an iterop in this part of project. So, incoming stream is a must

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin alright, I suppose the extension method would be the better way as it involves fewer conversions